# Single easier command to search in bash history

Tags: bash

On of the commands that I wrote the most on daily basis on my console is

```
# history | grep -i 'something'
```

That and `ctr+r` is probably what I use the most :).

I was thinking in have something like

```
# h something
```

Or even better, a live search like ctr+r but that shows all results at glance, not only one. I know i can cycle pressing `ctrl+r` again, but would be better if I could see what are all the elements that I"m  cycling.

So this is 2 questions:

1) Do you know any program that provide a better interface for bash history in console?

2) What is the best way to accomplish my `h something` alias?

Answer (score 2):

Want a **h** command. Easy, add an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.bash_aliases` (depending on your config).

```
alias h="history | grep -i"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may want to try https://github.com/dvorka/hstr which is "suggest box style" filtering of Bash history - you get `hh 'something'` - for instance `hh an`:

[image]

It can be easily bound to <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One way to acomplish the `h something` is adding to `.bash_profile`:

```
 alias h="history | grep -i "
```

I'm actually using zsh but i guess it will work too

Answer (score 0):

In my .bash_profile is set the following in there:

> set -o vi

then I have the functionality of vi from the command line

Hitting the ESCape key followed by k will return the last line entered

ESC-k

keep hitting k so that it scrolls up.  The magic happens when you then hit the slash key (/). Then you can search your history

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/do-you-like-to-perform-vi-style-editing-in-bash-command-line/

Comment: so ESC+k / ESC+j is like arrow up/down?

I were not able to use the / key, is like wrote a couple of letters and next press J / K?

Comment: ESC activates vi then k (lower case) be default you are at the bottom of history so j only works once you have gone "up" with k.  I typically out of habit do ESC+k / to search but really Esc+/ would work too.

Comment: Also make sure that you have set -o vi activated (at the command line works for testing). If you type something on the command line its easier to notice that its working. Once you hit ESC+/ the text will go away and the slash (/) will be there.  type what you are looking for hit enter the it will show if its in history.  Then n for next match